# Compile standalone Matlab guide program for Windows using Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using Matlab R2016a. I'm following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b_NmBEW9ak) to compile my Matlab guide program as standalone application. However I can only see options to compile it for a Linux platform. Is it also possible to compile it for Windows using the Linux version of Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, at present, the answer to your question is no. In Matlab you cannot achieve cross compilation of executables. The `Matlab Compiler` is strictly tied to the machine environment.

The basic rule is that in order to build an executable that can run under operating system `X`,  it must be compiler under operating system `X`.

Therefore, you need to install the `Matlab Compiler` on a Windows machine to create an executable that can run under Windows. On the top of that, Windows represents a special case in which you have to consider the difference between `32` and `64` bit versions. For more infos, read these threads:

1. https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4649-deploy-for-windows-32-bit-from-a-64-bit-computer
2. https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/217297-32-bit-exe-compilation-using-matlab-64-installed
3. https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60904-compile-executable-for-64-bit-system